# Is a call using super.save(commit=False) needed on a Model Form parent class needed if only adding in additional attributes after form submit?

Tags: python, django

Or could I just use the regular form instances own `save(commit=False)` method?

Here's the code. I don't understand why this is needed. There is a signal that created the a profile extension instance but it's called `post_save`. (I don't think there's much use in the signal here either).

The model view call on `save` is pretty basic too, no additional form handling other than calling `save`.

Any guidance here is much appreciated.

views.py:

```
class ProfileSignupView(CreateView):
    model = CustomUser
    form_class = ProfileSignupForm
    template_name = 'accounts/profile_signup.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user) 
        return render(self.request, "accounts/userdash.html", {user: user.id})
```

forms.py:

```
class ProfileSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
 
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):  
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)
    
    def save(self): 
        data = super().save(commit=False) # <-- why is this needed? 
        data.is_local = True
        data.save() 
        return data
```

signals.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def create_user_type(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.is_local == True:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `save(commit=False)` is used to add things to the form object before it gets saved to the database.

In this particular case, it really depends under what circumstance you want the value to be added.

As it is, it will be added every time that form type is used - this could be a DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) approach if you know it should be added to all uses of the form.

Another approach, at the view level, is to use

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.is_local = True
    user = form.save()
    ...
```

In some ways this is preferable, as it means you will never accidentally add the field while saving unvalidated data. You can also re-use the form elsewhere without adding that additional field, should you need to.